# How to add a graph in each tab of a QTabWidget

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqtgraph, qtabwidget

I am new to PyQt4, creating a simple GUI. I want to create a window which contains multiple tabs, and in each tab one graph should be plotted. I am able to create a tab with buttons in the bottom, but unable to add a graph in each tab, so I am requesting help.

[image]

Comment: Your current question is extensive, for example to what type of graphics you mean, you know how to make the graphics ?, please show your code.

Comment: Show the code you have so far and we'll tell you where the error is.

Comment: I want to plot a graph in two different tabs, but i am getting in only one tab here is the image of the output which i got (please click the link) https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B0OO2qfk5Qs-aGpvSk1mUFYtS2s

Comment: Sir, I understand your problem but in order to help you, we need you to show us your code.

Comment: Here is the link for the file which contains code : https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B0OO2qfk5Qs-TXVmS2I3eFk3UWc

Comment: Sir , Please help me in this regard

Comment: see this: https://gist.github.com/eyllanesc/33b1aa2e110fda24cd7c7d00314e067f

Comment: Thank you very much   @eyllanesc  Sir.It's Exactly output which i expected

Comment: Please delete this question, I also recommend to layout the GUI before starting to write code.

Comment: ok Sir sure, Sir i want to plot the instantaneous values of the graph in left side which function should i use

Comment: Change the order in which the widgets are added to the layout, in the code that I showed you first put the buttons and then the plot, now add the plot first and then the buttons.